# How can I make the scroll button on the right side not in the middle of table?

Tags: html, css

#### HTML Codes

```html
<table id="container", cellspacing="0">
     <thead>
         <tr>
             <th>Commands</th>
             <th>Aliases</th>
             <th>Description</th>
         </tr>
     </thead>
     <tbody>
         <tr>
             <td>help</td>
             <td>Help</td>
             <td>List all available commands on AnVolt with description</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
             <td>clean</td>
             <td>Purge</td>
             <td>Clean total messages in current channel</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
             <td>userinfo</td>
             <td>Profile</td>
             <td>Gives you information about specific users, default is your profile</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
             <td>serverinfo</td>
             <td>GuildInfo</td>
             <td>Gives you information about current server/guild, such a member count</td>
         </tr>
     </tbody>
 </table>
```

#### CSS Codes

```css
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px #000;
    text-align: left;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 65%;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    position: fixed;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

table thead {
    background-color: #000;
    color: #fff;
}

table th,
table td {
    padding: 16px 32px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: 700;
}

table tbody {
    display:block;
    height:100px;
    overflow:auto;
    float:right;
    width:100%;
}
```

Image related to the Table: [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Wk9F.png). The image shows that the scroll button is in the middle of the image but I want to make it on the right side, anyone can help me out?

Edit: I've been added my HTML Codes. If there's any problem or any unnecessary codes, you can delete or edit the codes. Thanks!

Comment: Please provide a ​​[minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Include HTML in the [mcve] as well

Comment: What do you want it to look like on say narrow viewports in landscape mode (with potentially two scroll bars)? Would it be obvious to the user what they are scrolling?

Answer (score 1):

This way you can do it:

```
<div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th scope="col">Command</th>
          <th scope="col">Status</th>
          <th scope="col">Description</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <th scope="row">
            Command Text
          </th>
          <td scope="row">Yes</td>
          <td scope="row">Description Description Description Description Description Description Description
            Description Description Description Description Description</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th scope="row">
            Command Text
          </th>
          <td scope="row">Yes</td>
          <td scope="row">Description Description Description Description Description Description Description
            Description Description Description Description Description</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th scope="row">
            Command Text
          </th>
          <td scope="row">Yes</td>
          <td scope="row">Description Description Description Description Description Description Description
            Description Description Description Description Description</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th scope="row">
            Command Text
          </th>
          <td scope="row">Yes</td>
          <td scope="row">Description Description Description Description Description Description Description
            Description Description Description Description Description</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th scope="row">
            Command Text
          </th>
          <td scope="row">Yes</td>
          <td scope="row">Description Description Description Description Description Description Description
            Description Description Description Description Description</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th scope="row">
            Command Text
          </th>
          <td scope="row">Yes</td>
          <td scope="row">Description Description Description Description Description Description Description
            Description Description Description Description Description</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th scope="row">
            Command Text
          </th>
          <td scope="row">Yes</td>
          <td scope="row">Description Description Description Description Description Description Description
            Description Description Description Description Description</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th scope="row">
            Command Text
          </th>
          <td scope="row">Yes</td>
          <td scope="row">Description Description Description Description Description Description Description
            Description Description Description Description Description</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th scope="row">
            Command Text
          </th>
          <td scope="row">Yes</td>
          <td scope="row">Description Description Description Description Description Description Description
            Description Description Description Description Description</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th scope="row">
            Command Text
          </th>
          <td scope="row">Yes</td>
          <td scope="row">Description Description Description Description Description Description Description
            Description Description Description Description Description</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th scope="row">
            Command Text
          </th>
          <td scope="row">Yes</td>
          <td scope="row">Description Description Description Description Description Description Description
            Description Description Description Description Description</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th scope="row">
            Command Text
          </th>
          <td scope="row">Yes</td>
          <td scope="row">Description Description Description Description Description Description Description
            Description Description Description Description Description</td>
        </tr>
        
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
```

```
.table-responsive {
    border: 1px solid #D4D4D4;
    border-radius: 5px;
    vertical-align: middle !important;
    -webkit-box-shadow: rgb(0 0 0 / 10%) 0 2px 4px;
    -moz-box-shadow: rgb(0 0 0 / 10%) 0 2px 4px;
    box-shadow: rgb(0 0 0 / 10%) 0 2px 4px;
    height: 400px;
    overflow-y: auto;
    overflow-x: auto;
}
table {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    text-align: left;
    width: 100%;
    color: #212529;
    border: 1px solid #D4D4D4;
    caption-side: bottom;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    display: table;
    text-indent: initial;
    border-spacing: 2px;
}

table thead {
    position: sticky;
    top: 0px;
    z-index: 2;
    vertical-align: bottom;
}
table thead th{ 
    background-color: #2b2d3b;
    vertical-align: middle !important;
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: 500;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 16px;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 42px;
    padding: 0.5rem 0.5rem;
 }
 table thead th:first-child {
    border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
}
table thead th:last-child {
    border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
}
table tbody {
    border-top: inherit !important;
    vertical-align: middle !important;
}
table tbody td, table tbody th{  
height: 46px;
padding: 0.5rem 0.5rem;
line-height: 36px;
padding-top: 5px;
padding-bottom: 5px;
background-color: #fff;
border-bottom-color: #D4D4D4;
vertical-align: middle !important;
color: #545454;
font-weight: 400;
font-size: 14px;
text-overflow: ellipsis;
white-space: nowrap;
overflow: hidden;
border-bottom: 1px solid #D4D4D4;
}
```

Or check in jsfiddle example link :
https://jsfiddle.net/DeveloperSandip/5jhpv0xq/6/